# VueJS Passing computed data as a prop returns undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've tried and tried, but i can't figure it out the problem. From what I could read elsewhere, the variable passed to the child component gets sent as `undefined` before the data is available in the parent.

Please see here for reference:

[the code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/01rz0l993w)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <child :parentData="data.message"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from "./components/Child";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Child
  },
  computed: {
    quote() { return 'Better late than never' }
  },
  data() {
    return {

      data: { message: this.quote } ,

    thisWorks: { message: "You can see this message if you replace what is passed to the child"  }

    };
  }

};
</script>
```

Then in the child:

```
<template>
  <div>
  <h1>I am the Child Component</h1>
  <h2> {{ parentData }}</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Child",
  props: {            
      parentData: { type: String, default: "I don't have parent data" },   
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: change `<Child :parentData="data.message"/>` to `<child :parentData="data.message"/>` because html doesn't use uppercase letters and use your computed property directly like ` <child :parentData="quote"/>`

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I can't pass the quote directly, this is a simplified example of a a v-for loop that uses data from vuex specific to each element being passed. I've replicated the data structure in the example.

Comment: you are doing it wrong, i think that you don't understand the role of computed property, you could a data object property in a computed one but you can't the reverse

Comment: Data properties are created before computed properties.  Always put related code in your question, a fiddle is great, but it shouldn't be the only reference in your question.

Comment: OK @devon point taken.

Comment: check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/r67j7x774), i recommend to not use reserved words like `data`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is, you cannot access the value of `this.quote` because at the moment the `data object`is creating, the `computed object` actually does not exist.

This is an alternative, we will use the `created()` lifecycle hook to update the value of `data object`:

```
  created(){
    this.data = {
      message: this.quote
    }
  },
```

You don't need to change any things, just adding those line of codes is enough.

I've already tested those codes in your CodeSandbox project and it works like a charm.

Hopefully it helps!

Comment: yep! I know it's messy. However, what I'm trying to do is solving the author's problem with respecting the author's codes. I could re-write it all while still satisfy the application logic.

Comment: stackoverflow it's not just to solve problems but it allows people to learn something in the good way

Comment: I'm agree with you! Then, an advice for @martinval is, you should directly pass the `quote` computed property to `child component` like this: `<child :parentData="quote"/>`. It would be much easier.

Comment: OK, so "I'm doing it wrong". What is the right way to do this then ? I'm sure this is a pretty common use case: A parent component is getting data that it needs to pass to in a v-for to a child....